# Google Analytics regards direct access as referral for subdomain

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, referrer

When I directly access `subdomain.mydomain.com` by entering it in the browser's address bar, Google Analytics Realtime Overview indicates that top referral is `mydomain.com`.

I'm sure that I'm the only visitor of my website at that moment (It is just one visitor from my location).

I expect that it should indicate for Top Referral: `There is no data for this view.`

What is the cause of this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as a "self-referral" and is to be expected, as indicated [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3198398?hl=en):

> If your Google Analytics implementation is configured to measure
>   sessions across multiple domains and/or subdomains, a marginal level
>   of self-referrals may be natural.

As also indicated, there may be `many different scenarios that can lead to a self-referral.`

If you're interested in determining what these might be, follow the guide [there](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3198398?hl=en) under "Determining the origin of self-referrals" and "Common causes and solutions for self-referrals".